# How do I show $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification

> Let $\alpha\in\Bbb C\setminus\{-1\}$ be a root of the polynomial $x^5+1$. Show that $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=4$.

---

**My attempt:**

Let $p(x)=x^5+1=(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$. Now assume that $q(x)=(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$.

Claim: The polynomial $q(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Replace $x$ with $x-1$, then $q(x-1)=x^4-5x^3+10x^2-10x+5$. By Eisenstein criteria, this polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ for $p=5$. So, there exist a field extension $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, and $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=$degree of minimal polynomial.

In this case, $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=4$.

Can anyone suggest me some improvement or mistakes in this solution?

Comment: You mean "If $\alpha\ne-1$"

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I mean $\alpha \neq -1$

Comment: You can nonchalantly use `\Bbb Q` for the output $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: You could have considered $q(-x)$, which cyclotomic polynomial and so irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ . This also implies $q(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct. You showed that $q(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (since $q(\alpha) = 0$ and $q$ is irreducible). Thus

$$|\mathbb{Q}(\alpha): \mathbb{Q}| = \deg q = 4$$